# How to create a list of a list of integers based on a tree of Or and And objects?

Tags: c#, algorithm, dart, recursion

I want this result:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4,5,6],[1,4,5,7]]
```

from the following set of objects:

```
var andsOrs = 
  Ands(items: [
    single(1),
    Ors(items: [
      single(2),
      single(3),
      Ands(items: [
        single(4),
        single(5),
        Ors(items: [
          single(6),
          single(7),
        ]),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]);
```

I'm struggling to write a function that would produce the output, can anyone help?  Any modern object oriented language would be fine really, c#, js, dart, c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for functions named `Ands`, `Ors` and `single` that will give the desired result. The format of the desired result is a 2D array where the inner arrays list atomic values that are AND'ed, and the outer array lists items that are OR'ed.

Each of those functions should return that format, also `single`. So for instance, `single(1)` should return `[[1]]`.

The `Ors` function should just concatenate the 2D items it gets as argument into a longer 2D array. So if for instance, `Ors` gets two items: `[[1,2]]` and `[[3,4],[5,6]]` then the return value should be `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`.

The more complex one is `Ands`: it should perform a Cartesian product on the arguments it gets.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript. The notation of the input is a bit different, as `items:`  as function argument would be invalid syntax. We can just pass each item as a separate argument and use spread syntax:

```js
function single(i) {
    return [[i]];
}

function Ands(first, ...rest) {
    // Cartesian product, using recursion
    if (!rest.length) return first;
    let restResult = Ands(...rest);
    let result = [];
    for (let option of first) {
        for (let restOption of restResult) {
            result.push([...option, ...restOption]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function Ors(...items) {
    return items.flat(1); // Reduces 1 level of array depth (from 3 to 2)
    // Alternative syntax to get the same result:
    // return [].concat(...items)
}

var andsOrs = 
  Ands(
    single(1),
    Ors(
      single(2),
      single(3),
      Ands(
        single(4),
        single(5),
        Ors(
          single(6),
          single(7),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

console.log(andsOrs);
```

Comment: That's great, thanks so much @trincot, I'd actually just figured it out but hopefully it was a nice little quiz anyway.  I still get confused with these types of functions after so many years programming!  I think anything with recursion just confuses me initially.  Writing it out helps though.